# Inserciones masivas en MongoDB con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, insert

Estoy usando python + MongoDB con pymongo
hasta ahora todo esta bien

pero ahora quisiera optimizar los insert, lo que realizo es leer un csv con 50000 filas y creo un bucle para leer fila a fila, pasando a json y realizar la inserción (insert), demora bastante pero sube XD

*problemas ahora tengo unos 200 ficheros csv que tiene entre 50000 y 150000 filas
y ya se hace insostenible*

**Quería saber si existe alguna forma de hacer inserciones masivas en MongoDB**

ejemplo en postgressql esta la instrucción *copy*, que sube un fichero completo a la bd

gracias de antemano, un saludo

Comment: Estas inserciones masivas no son nada buenas en MongoDB. Dependiendo del número de nodos podrías echar abajo toda la base de datos (¿Algún motivo para usar mongo en lugar de una postgres?). Una opción es usar la utilidad [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/), previa desactivación del journal.

Comment: así han creado el sistema, con MongoDB, por eso quería saber si existia algun comando como el copy en postgressql pero en mongo.